# "in the most important of several staffing changes"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> "Severus Snape, long-standing Potions master at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, was today appointed Headmaster **in the most important of several staffing changes** at the ancient school. ..."
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I don't understand the phrase "in the most important of several staffing changes". "in the most important of" doesn't look grammatical and I haven't found it defined in any dictionaries. How should we understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several staff changes. And the most important one and most significant change was that of Severus Snape who was appointed headmaster.